# Making new map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping

I'm new using QGIS. I have been searching for information, a manual or a workbook that shows me how to make a map like this.

[image]

I require the same map but with other division and new data.

I have been reading about shapefiles and how to make maps in QGIS. I watched a couple of videos but they don't show me how to make this.

Comment: A map like this is basically just adding a shapefile to qgis (drag&drop). You can style it by right clicking the layer in the layerlist on the left, selecting propertys and editing within style tab. Where are you stuck at and what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Open QGIS then use the add vector layer. What you're showing isn't much of a map, it's just the canvas with a vector layer. If you need the same colours then go to the layer properties, symbology tab and change the symbology to that colour. BTW spatial-analyst is an Esri product so you should probably remove that tag.

Comment: Well, I have to do a map like this but with other separations and I have to aggregate data for doing a global spatial analysis using the statistic Moran's I and local spatial analysis using the statistic G*. But I don't know how to change the separation lines and aggregate my data.

Comment: What data are you using and what separations do you want to have? What shall your map display? To slice a simple polygon by hand use the "Split Features" tool from advanced digitizing toolbar: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#split-features. (Guide is for 2.18, but its the same in 3.x) Also take a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you're interested in QGIS. I only just today got back from the FOSS4G Oceania SoTM conference (best conference i've ever been to by the way) and have been talking with some new QGIS users about this very problem of where do new users start? It was highlighted to me that it's not so easy to know which way to go.

A couple of resources that you can try would be:

- [The QGIS training manul](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/)
- And for your particular question above you may want to start with [Adding your first layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/introduction/preparation.html)

One of the presentations I watched was from Hannah Dormido who is journalist and she outlined some of her hurdles when learning QGIS. She went from zero experience in QGIS or GIS and she now makes beautiful, simple, clean maps with QGIS (and one of my favourite cartographers - https://twitter.com/hannahdormido). A resource which she mentioned helped her were these youtube tutorials by Steven Bernard - [you can find the here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7HotvlLKHCs9nD1fFUjSOsZrsnctyV2R&app=desktop).